# imread throws [WARN] can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Tags: python, opencv, path

what can i do?

```
 WARN:0@0.726] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('pythonProject6/arrow.jpg'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\whatsapp try.py", line 17, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-

python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("pythonProject6/arrow.jpg")

#print(img.shape)

cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: Looks like "pythonProject6/arrow.jpg" is missing. Might be related to the current folder being different than what you expect. You can try passing a full path.

Comment: "C:\Users\PC2\PycharmProjects\pythonProject6\arrow.jpg"

Comment: why did you ignore the warning emitted by imread?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, make sure you have defined default folder in python correctly. then check the file and address spelling. if it did not resolve, then try this:(use r and instead of / use //.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(r"pythonProject6//arrow.jpg")

#print(img.shape)

cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

If it did not resolve, check your file attribution, and uncheck hidden and read-only. always check you can view the image by windows photo viewer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using VS Code on macOS. The path was correct, but I was getting the same warning, and the resulting image of `cv2.imread` was empty.

The issue was solved when I gave Full Disk Access to VS Code. I figured it out because I managed to run the code using my terminal (instead of VS Code terminal).

`System Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Full Disk Access`

Answer (score -2):

The latest versions of opencv 4.6.x.y and later have the cv2.imshow() issue. I experienced the same. If solution is:
First

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

Second:

```
pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.5.62
```

Comment: "have the issue"? what issue? the only issue here is that `imread` actually WARNED that the file could not be found, when it just kept quiet before. **bad answer**.